# Django template tags loop in condition for comma separation

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

This is my current condition:

```
   {% for d in datalist %}
   <span class="bold">{{ d }}, </span>
   {% endfor %}
```

For example, in datalist, the datalist is a queryset, i have these `['t;, 'b', 'c']`

I need to show this data like thise `t,b,c.`

in the last item, there should be a fullstop/dot, and after each item, there should comma

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way of handling this would be with the forloop attributes:

```
{% for d in datalist %}
<span class="bold">{{ d }}{% if forloop.last %}.{% else %}, {% endif%}</span>
{% endfor %}
```